# Preventing frequent cookie prompts

Tags: support

I log on to this site from my Windows device occasionally, e.g., once every 1-2 weeks. Frequently, when I log in, I see a prompt asking me to either accept or customize my cookie settings. **Is there a way to configure these settings once and prevent it from appearing again, or at least for a long time?**

Needless to say, seeing this prompt so often is a little annoying. And as someone who only wants websites to use *strictly necessary* cookies, I don't want to click the (also annoying) "Accept all cookies" button.

[image]

Comment: Are you using an ad blocker?  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363872/177408

Comment: Yep, that must be it. Thanks for pointing me to that other Q&A.

Comment: Perhaps this question should be closed then?  It isn't specific to Mathematics Educators.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was already answered on the main meta site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a duplicate of: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362091/the-cookie-consent-dialog-coming-from-cookielaw-org-keeps-popping-up/363872#363872